# Will high reputation in Stack Overflow help to get a good job?

Tags: career-development

In a [post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20369/career-advice-stay-with-php-or-start-a-new-career-in-something-else-net/20373#20373), Joel Spolsky mentioned that 5 digit Stack Overflow reputation can help you to earn a job paying $100k+. How much of that is real?

Would anyone like to share their success in getting a high paid job by virtue of their reputations on Stack Exchange sites?

I read somewhere that, a person got an interview offer from Google because a recruiter found his Stack Overflow reputation to be impressive. Anyone else with similar stories?

Comment: That's anecdotal evidence as user8149 has also demonstrated. If there isn't statistical evidence or actual case studies, it isn't reliable.

Comment: I would upvote this 1000x if I could. Was thinking exactely the same :-).

Comment: pretty sure this s a duplicate ?

Comment: @Gio, do you have a link to the demonstration by user8149?

Comment: not exact, but very similar: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/12070/would-you-put-your-stackoverflow-profile-link-on-your-cv-resume

Comment: You neglected to add that he finished that statement "without an interview", which should indicate a fair bit of sarcasm.

Comment: $100K in NYC is $25K in Chattanooga, TN.

Comment: If I were in position to hire, then I would like to read someone's questions and answers on SO, but would still need a face check and an interview. Salary is determined by many factors.

Comment: I expect answers no matter what they are would spawn a lot of reputation leeches.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a very secure limb and say *in my personal experience*, yes.

Comment: I think the blog that you are quoting is http://www.cforcoding.com/2010/07/my-google-interview.html. I just read it yesterday.

Comment: I wish that a high reputation on Superuser would get a high paying sys admin job! - Anyone in London/UK need a sys admin!?

Comment: @Marc, please share your experiences.

Comment: @Thorbjørn - I'll add as an answer.

Comment: If a question is upvoted 85 times, with multiple answer ranging from 10 to 92 upvotes, how can you say it's not constructive?

Comment: @Josh K: Not constructive questions usually get multiple answers and votes. It's exactly what we want avoid here. For me this question turn's on a forum thread. See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/544/questions-like-a-forum-thread. Click on all "show more comments", see whole page and ask to yourself if this is a question or a forum thread.

Comment: @bigown: I believe that this question isn't a "forum thread" but rather one with a proper question (*"Will high reputation get me a good job"*) and quite a few answers. That is my opinion.

Comment: I can't believe a question with 97 upvotes, answers with more than 100 upvotes, 27 answers in total and participation from Joel himself got closed... WTF, is this some kind of sick joke?

Comment: @Steven A. Lowe 25K in The Philippines gets you a house, lot, expensive watch, lots of platinum credit cards and I forget what else. Thanks for pointing out that what matters is your ability to advance your quality of life, whatever you think that might be, wherever you are.

Comment: @ammoQ Participation from Joel, or Jeff, or the entire team behind SO does not grant a question some kind of immunity from being closed. It only ensures that the question (and subsequent answers) linger longer in the "should we delete this or re-open it" queue. If Joel posts a breaching experiment here, such as "How do I move the turtle in LOGO?", I will vote to close it just like any other noise. Judge a question on merit, not who answered it.

Comment: This question is overly subjective, caters to a specific moment in time (recalc, anyone?) and could have been asked on a broader scale (ohloh, cia.vc, etc). Additionally, it is specific to only one geographical location. Voting to close as too localized.

Comment: @Tim Post: Great!

Comment: @Tim Post: Sure, if Joel made fun of us, closing would be a proper action. On the other hand, pushing the "close" button is not expression of an opinion, it's actually moderation. IMO good moderation is reluctant. As a moderator, when I see that many people enjoy a topic and it doesn't completely violate the rules, I leave it open even if I personally don't like it.

Comment: @Tim: This doesn't cater to a specific moment in time. The recalc was meant to balance questions vs. answers, not influence your ability to be hired. It is also (as pointed out by several people describing job offers not in their local) specific to one location. You're way off base, but really it doesn't matter because I don't think this question will stay closed.

Comment: @ammoQ I am a retired moderator from an established SE site, and my vote stands. Again, the answer (from whomever may be notable) is incidental. It is only the question that I consider. I still feel that this is (entirely) too localized, and support my vote to close it as such. Consider, if you will the number of programmers (not the number of users, the number of actual productive participants on SO) VS the number of actual programmers in the world. Again, far too localized. This site is about programmers in general, not just SO users.

Comment: @ammoQ Re-phrase this question. Does my Ohloh/Cia.vc/Affero/Whatever-nongnu-implements/Patch-credit-in-foo/etc help me to get a good job? SO is no different than any third party that offers a rank that (might) put you above another, until the next recalc. This really needs to be closed, as it may actually mislead people. The point of this site is answers to questions, no matter how subjective, that can be (reasonably) trusted.

Comment: @Tim: If you think that SO is just another site and nothing special, then "No, nobody cares about your SO reputation" is a perfectly valid answer, but that doesn't invalidate the question. IMO it's not localized at all. Localized questions are questions like "which company in southern Detroit offers the best work environment", which only concerns a small percentage of all members. It's fair to assume that a large majority of members of this site are also members of stackoverflow, so the question concerns most of them.

Comment: @ammoQ Localized questions are those that reach a short audience. By way of comparison to a question that would interest thousands, this is far too localized. I respect you, I understand your point of view and my vote still stands. Should rep on SO ever become an industry accepted deciding factor (beyond a non constructive debate, which this question begs) I'd ask the same question. Currently, any answer serves to document a negative or an anomaly, which is why my vote still stands. Is this useful for anyone who doe not have 10k+ on SO?

Comment: @ammoQ Additionally, we're discussing pointing people at a numerical score that is __far from static__ by its own definition. That may or may not be a good idea, an accepted answer is only one use case. This is just way too subjective to serve as authoritative. Like it or not, most Googlers don't scroll down beyond the text that serves them best. Take this up on a blog.

Comment: "Is this useful for anyone who does not have 10k+ on SO"? Good question. If we assume that readers of this site have a fair chance to get such a reputation, then yes, it's useful for them, since they might or might not invest their time in working towards the 10k goal. If we assume that Joe Average Programmer will hardly reach that goal, then you have a point. Good thing both of us don't have to worry anymore ;-)

Comment: @ammoQ I have enjoyed this debate. I think we, at this point agree to disagree. I don't want to seem pessimistic, but I look forward to disagreeing with you again! Thank you for being professional, articulate and quite friendly :) It appears, however that we're starting a bit of a comment war, which perhaps isn't the best idea. We've done (what I think) is an adequate job of stating our points. Good show :)

Comment: OK, I agree to agree to disagree with you. I'm also fond of a good discussion. :D

Comment: "Will a good resume and proven track record help to get a good job?" It's not the only thing (the interview matters) but it can certainly help.

Answer (score 266, accepted):

## No

> the real answer: spend a few months earning a five digit Stack Overflow reputation, and you'll be getting job offers in the $100K+ range without an interview.

There is no reason why a high reputation (or "score") on any site will get you a job at all. I have pointed this out before, you are more likely to get a job by maintaining open source projects, writing proficiently, leaving good impressions, and making personal connections within the community.

Are these people good programers? *Undoubtedly yes!* Does that mean they are a good fit for your team? **Absolutely not**. Calling these people "superstars" may be completely correct, but that doesn't make them perfect. <sup>1</sup>

What determines if you are a good fit? Interviews and connections. You can't replace meeting people face to face with a number.

---

Having a high reputation can't hurt, **but it isn't a magic bullet**.

---

<sup>1: In no way do I mean to imply these people are bad programmers, I mean to emphasize the inability to instantly and wholly judge someone based on a number.</sup>

Comment: Well-written questions and answers on StackOverflow is quite indicative of your communication skills, though.

Comment: @Josh I agree BUT there may be an indirect connection between reputation on a site like StackOverflow and job offerings. My line of thought is that if you can score 10000+ points by giving meaningful answers, you probably have a considerable amount of knowledge about some technology / topic.

Comment: @Thorb: Correct. I tend to take my answers and expand on them in my [blog](http://joshuakehn.com/blog/) time permitting. I get far more inquiries from that then all the SO / SE sites put together.

Comment: I hope it doesn't. I've seen some really stupid questions asked repeatedly by people with high reputations and stupid answers by others.

Comment: @christian.p: Cause / effect - do you get offered a job because you have 10000+ points, or because you're good at what you do and spent some time sharing that information on a website?

Comment: The question asks whether having a high rep *helps*. Of course you don't just get an offer without the usual hiring process just because of your rep.

Comment: @MAK: The original question asked it reputation by itself would earn you a job.

Comment: @Cthulhu Like I said, this is an indirect connection. High reputation is certainly a plus. It can show dedication/will to help others to solve problems.

Comment: @Thorb: While I agree with your general sentiment, I see a *lot* of SO questions whose answer owed its high score to being submitted in the first few minutes than to it being well-written.  It's not to the "First post!" level yet, though.

Comment: @Josh K, I have intended to start doing exactly that, has that been working out well?

Comment: @Mike, I said well-written, not highly scored.

Comment: @instanceofTom: I'm not sure what you're referencing, do you mean my blog? Yes, it works out very well.

Comment: @Josh K, yes your blog.

Comment: @instanceofTom: Yes, it works out very well. Coding it was fun, writing for it is better.

Comment: "Are these people good programers? Undoubtedly yes!".  I've read some of the code from a couple of the 5-digit  folks...not exactly impressive from what I've seen.  I would say that there's quite a bit of social massaging involved - if you can say something that appeals to a large group of people then you win...end game.  While most are quite capable there are (and the numbers are growing) too many trolls and flame-baiters just looking for the +1 to make their day successful.

Comment: Are you saying that playing Guitar Hero all day will not make me a rock star?

Comment: @Andrew Sledge: yes, as [Pavel Shved put it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55822/do-we-need-assume-good-faith-like-wikipedia): "For Stack Overflow the better principle is "assume rep wh*ring". If you see that a post seems unhelpful, your default assumption should be that the author didn't want to do any harm, he just intended to get some quick rep."

Comment: Just because someone may not be a fit for every job doesn't mean they aren't a fit for a lot of other jobs that may pay in this price range.

Comment: 1. I've seen people writing huge answers for blatant homework questions. they just want the points.  2. I looked into advertising a programmer job, in my major city (>5m people) there were 60 registered SO users. It isn't a good place for us to advertise for developers.

Comment: Being able to use semicolons properly, rather than using commas improperly, will also lend higher credibility to your employment chances.

Answer (score 174):

## Yes

Come on, seriously: look at [the first page or two of Stack Overflow users](https://stackoverflow.com/users). Pick anyone at random. Look at three or four of the highly voted answers they wrote. If you've ever hired a programmer in your life, it's obvious those people are all some of the best programmers you could ever hire.

Then keep going deeper and deeper. Scroll to page 5. Edit the URL and go right to page 100 where they have reputations in the 3000 range. Look at everyone. With the very rare exception of someone who got a lot of points for a silly answer, these are all obvious superstar programmers... the kind that most teams would kill for.

Will this actually get them jobs? Ultimately, [we're betting it will](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/). You'll have to find a company where there are actual technical people making hiring decisions, not resume-reading-monkey-recruiters. And you may have to find a city to live in where there are a lot of good programming jobs: if you really, really don't want to leave Roswell, New Mexico, you'll be limited to a vanishingly small number of telecommuting jobs. But if you're in the top, say, 5000 Stack Overflow users, and you can work in Silicon Valley, New York, Seattle, Boston, Austin, Research Triangle, London, Hyderabad, Bangalore, Sydney, Beijing, or Tel Aviv, I would be **extremely** surprised if you aren't in high demand and earning in the top 10 percentile.

Comment: "But Joel, who wants to hire someone who spends their whole day on Stack Overflow?"

Comment: Spending your day on Stack Overflow implies that you are *underemployed*. These people spending their whole day on Stack Overflow would love to have a better, more interesting job. They're the perfect candidates. We hire them all the time (at Stack Overflow) and they stop earning reputation once we give them useful important work instead of the drivel their previous employer had them working on.

Comment: My 5-digit rep at the time I interviewed must not have been high enough for Fog Creek. I believe I was even on page 3 at the time. My point being, you have to admit you wouldn't hire every 10K+ Stack Overflow user, or I missed the part in my rejection email where I got the $100K offer. (I'm intentionally antagonizing you, I hope we're still friends :)

Comment: i didn't say anyone would hire you, i just said you'll be in high demand ;) Besides, tell me with a straight face being developer evangelist for Twilio isn't a great job.

Comment: Oh, I love my job! Not being hired by Fog Creek was probably the best thing that happened to me :) (composing an answer about how SO participation turned into that job....)

Comment: Currently on [Page 59](http://stackoverflow.com/users?page=59&tab=reputation)... Prolly not gonna land me a $100k job :(

Comment: The question isn't *"Are these great programmers"* the question is *"How does SO rank influence pay and employability"*. I think that how much reputation you have on StackOverflow is not an employability grade. That's what [careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) is for. Having a high reputation can't hurt, **but it isn't a magic bullet**.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring But nothing to scoff at either. I would show that off to every prospective employer.

Comment: I'm exhibit A.  Was ranked #5 at one point thanks in part to poor work environment where I ended spending _way_ too much time on SO.  All that effort actually helped get me fired, but not before I'd earned an MS MVP award and found a new job that better uses my skills (was planning to put in my 2 weeks notice a week later, but I think they got wind of the new gig first.)  Since then, I just don't seem to have near as much time for SO.

Comment: @josh I wish you had written that in your answer "it's not a magic bullet" that's the real crux of the issue.

Comment: I'm hovering around 3000th place, and it took me over 3 months of applications to get a single interview (which ended up being in IT, not programming), with about half my resumes mentioning my SO profile.
Hiring is effectively random, any thoughts to the contrary are biased by inside information or undue influence.

Comment: @joel sadly, i've been so busy i've dropped to page 5. and jon skeet's rep is now 8.33 times mine. we were once so close... (not really!)

Comment: @Joel-Splosky Emm, Joel, are you underemployed to spend your day here?

Comment: I would not agree to everybody on page 100 being great. I'm on page 16 and there are many people in that range whom I'd never hire. Perhaps having two gold tag badges for unrelated tags could be a sufficient indicator (I don't have any yet myself)? But apart from that I'd say: sure, it should be one of the things to put on a resume if you've got at least 10k rep. But hiring people for SO rep alone? Only the first 5 pages or so.

Comment: @S.P.Floyd: probably because being a technical genius is not enough.

Comment: @Joel - not every single employer out there (even the well payhing ones) is brilliant enough to recognize a SO user with a high rep is both **underemployed** and **brilliant**. Underemployed or not, it treads on questionable ethics to spend so much time ***IF*** an underployed developer spends so much time on SO while on the clock.

Comment: @Pierre303 and you don't even have to be a genius to get to page 100

Comment: @S.P.Floyd: and on page 10?

Comment: @Pierre303 hopefully I'll be there in a month or two, and then I'll tell you :-)

Comment: I think the background of the developer still has a lot to do with it though. I've got a reasonable high reputation on Stack Overflow (pushing 5,000) but I haven't seen it being of any use when applying for jobs. Granted some of my reputation is from silly things as opposed to firm technical questions and answers, but I don't see it as a huge help. Part of the problem might be due to being more of a scientific applications developer as opposed to a generalist developer - does tend to move the resume in a given direction.

Comment: I got most of my rep from a [stupid answer][1].  I spend a lot of time answering old questions that never get voted up though, so I think it works itself out.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo/1003886#1003886

Comment: @Joel What? You're not allowed to answer questions about you. We're talking about you, that means you can only listen.

Comment: @Joel, I cannot agree more with your comment. I find that my best time of the day is spent on StackOverflow answering interesting questions. I am not saying I don't do work..in fact I do all of the work for a company that has no idea what WPF is (while I built a project entirely in WPF) and does not care for their developers, being *undervalued* and *unrecognized* is an understatement of my position. One of these day's I'll gather enough courage to apply for a StackOverflow developer position.

Comment: Wow, I am surprised to hear that a rep of 3000 is an indicator of a superstar programmer. I am at 3800 right now and have never considered myself to be a superstar. I thought the superstars were the guys with 50K+

Comment: @Joel Spolsky: There should be great effort spent to spread the word. I've never met an employer who had any concept of what SO was, or what its significance is. Until then, Josh K is right.

Comment: @John Isaacks, you need to adjust for inflation.  The only valid measurement of StackOverflow-karma is milliSkeet (I'm at 70).

Comment: @Thorbjorn: lol I wish I could pronouce your first name :)

Comment: @Thorbjørn: I am at 5,25 milliSkeet. Great measure. :)

Comment: The problem is recruiters. The majority of them haven't looked at Stackoverflow and they're too busy trying to match up keywords in a job description with whoever has the most of those keywords on their resume.

Comment: First nice to know I have found a site where Joel Spolsky posts having spent so long reading his blog in the past. I doubt myself that I would put my StackOverflow reputation score on my CV (never mind I use a strange alias here) or that anyone would take any notice of it. Aside, you just get reputation here by being quick on the button rather than giving the best answer. I missed out on a big score yesterday when someone beat me to posting exactly the same answer by a few seconds.

Comment: I've been offered a 360K AED (about 100K USD) JSF job in Dubai ~2 months back by someone who found me on SO. So yes, it definitely helps. No, I declined it. Over a half of salary would be wasted to property and school expenses which aren't cheap for non-locals (expats). I've 2 children. One year private school is already over one full month salary per child. One year elcheapo property rental would already be at least 1/3 of year salary. Currently I'm happy enough with freelancing for US and Europe from home in a cheap country.

Comment: @Joel: Why don't we make it interesting? You hire every 5-digit SO-member who hasn't managed to find a $100K job. That would only seem fair right?

Comment: While not easy to get a high score, I wouldn't use just a SO score to determine the quality of a developer. This is for the same reason that I don't assume someone that has a MS MVP title is intelligent. The ability to regurgitate knowledge doesn't equal a good developer. Sorry but relying on one indication of skill is an amateur move at best. On a side note, While it doesn't occur often, it is funny to see someone answer get up-voted because of who they are or rep, even though it is wrong.

Comment: I wonder if Fog Creek would hire a high rep 50 year old programmer over a lower rep 25 year old, assuming both had the skills required for the position.  Certainly many companies strongly prefer to hire a candidate within the windows of zero to 3 years of experience after college graduation.

Comment: LOL, I'm 17 years old and I have 12.2K rep (and not just because of one insanely voted-up q/a).

Comment: @nightcracker you like Python :P

Comment: @aF. I sure do.

Answer (score 57):

It's not a case of direct causation. That is, having a high reputation does not *lead to* a high-paying job. Being intelligent, articulate, passionate and knowledgable lead to a high-paying job. It's just that those qualities *also* lead to a (generally) higher reputation on Stack Overflow as well. So you shouldn't be aiming for a high reputation score. You should be aiming to be intelligent, articulate, passionate and knowledgeable.

A higher reputation will just be a bonus.

**Edit**: I just found [the post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20369/career-advice-stay-with-php-or-start-a-new-career-in-something-else-net/20373/#20373) where Joel says that. He's saying *he* would hire someone with a 5 digit reputation on Stack Overflow, not that you'd be able to get *any* $100k+ job with a 5 digit reputation. Also, he's not saying that he wouldn't look at the actual *content* of your profile, so if you've just posted hundreds of junk questions in the hopes of artificially raising your score, it's not going to help you. Basically, he's using your reputation score as an indication of those qualities I mentioned above.

Comment: +1 for referencing the actual post, and also highlighting the fact that there is not a direct causal link it is a strong correlation at best

Comment: It's important to note that Joel saying he'd hire someone also is completely orthogonal to whether other employers have any idea what StackOverflow is, or why a number on that site should matter to them.

Comment: Correlation isn't Causation. I agree if you've manage to earn a high reputation, it's probably a sign that you are knowledgeable about the topics you've replied to and thus likely to earn more in a position you know a lot about.

Comment: @JKirchartz: Yep, that's what I'm trying to say... you managed to get it in one sentence :-)

Comment: Right. People who are skilled, knowledgeable, and communicate well will probably have a high rating on SO (if they spend time to write answers there).

Answer (score 37):

### Gaming the System?

Someone should do a study of whether having high rep on SO begets higher rep on SO. That is, once someone reaches critical mass of, say, over 20K rep, do their answers tend to attract more upvotes than other equally valid answers? Anecdotally speaking, I have noticed that low-ranked members will garner 1 or 2 points for answers that will garner higher-rep people (often answering later) 5 or 10 points. And I'm talking about answers that are qualitatively no different. Success begets success.

Comment: I've noticed that as well. And I recall Jon Skeet remarking on it in the comments to an answer he posted.

Comment: +1. This has become a trend on SO, where silliest answers of people with high-rep are upvoted 'just for the sake'.

Comment: Another thing to consider is how the "trendiness" of topics influences points awarded.  Questions generate a flurry of activity/views when first posted,  but this tails off sharply after the first 24-48 hours.  You can post an outstanding answer to a question that has been "played out" and it may never get voted up because people tend not to read that far down the page...

Comment: @evadeflow That spans in to the main issue with gaining experience on stack exchange sites, particularly SO.  The fact that the board is effectively "camped" by a lot of hardened posters.  It actually hinders answer quality as people race to be the first to post.  It is exceptionally common for people to post a one-liner answer, or as near as possible and then edit it in to a full post quickly.  Just to secure pole-position.

Comment: @Orbling, why would that inherently be a issue? Answering is basically problem solving. If one can succinctly give the seed of the solution in a sentence, why not post it immediately? Even taking rep into account, people on average only upvote *good* answers, be them short or long.

Comment: @Péter Török: *(resurrecting a very old conversation here)* Short answers are not a problem, stop-gap answers that are fillers to ensure early votes while the full answer is assembled and posted a couple of minutes later, often totally changing the initial answer are a problem.

Comment: @Orbling, agreed. Although I haven't seen this much in practice (but neither was I specifically looking for it). I have inadvertently committed it myself a few times though, judging from the comments I received.

Comment: In my opinion, high reputation on SO means "I spend a lot of time on the site answering tons of basic questions that every programmer can relate to".

Answer (score 31):

I have a 5 digit SO reputation, and my salary is barely half of what you mention.

Obviously a good SO reputation doesn't guarantee anything, but even though most recruiters don't even know what SO is, surely it's worth mentioning it in one's CV. It's *substantial*, after all, unlike all kinds of official-looking certifications from two-day courses etc.

On the other hand: while Joel has a point, your *activity on Q/A sites* isn't really supposed to define your salary in any way. It may be a proof of some proficiency and enthusiasm, but the recruiting company is interested in what you're going to do *for them* if they recruit you, not in your abilities to answer programming questions. So by all means, consider SO reputation as a part of your professional credibility, but don't expect it to be something huge.

Comment: Right reputation, wrong country...

Comment: Rep on SO depends on a lot of things, like how long you've been on SO, what time zone you live in, how many questions you answer, how skilled you are at providing *an* answer quickly, and how much other people agree with your answers. It might be an interesting number, but it deserves circumspection.

Comment: @Mike and what kind of questions you answer. Interested in languages like Prolog, Smalltalk, Common Lisp? Good like with getting a big score. Quick off the mark on SQL? Well, time it right and you'll get lots of points off really silly questions.

Comment: @Frank: Right, but one thing I seriously like about these forums or whatever they are - you get to argue/agree/learn from people from all over the globe.

Comment: The learning benefit is waaay more important than the "reputation benefit", IMO. In fact, there are people in SO's >10k league who don't use their real names nor even include any contact information. They seem to want to avoid personal reputation.

Comment: SO is also self-limiting. After a few similar questions have been asked then the opportunity to gain rep off further answers dimishes. SO rewards freshness.

Comment: @Gary Rowe: Definitely. It's interesting to see what they're going to do about this "reputation inflation". Currently someone with 6 months & 1k reputation has almost certainly been giving more & better answers per unit of time than someone with 2 years & 10k reputation. Most peoples' reputation curve is convex (sqrt() shaped), and I don't think it's (only) due to their personally diminishing participation.

Comment: @Joonas I've noticed the same thing - perhaps you should post a general question here or on SO meta? It certainly seems that there is a long tail of difficult technical questions that gain very low rep in contrast to easy entry level questions that score high.

Comment: @Gary: When I look at my SO answers' votes, the top 20 answers are totally subjective, non-technical answers. My best-rated purely technical answer has got 8 votes. It's quite understandable that subjective questions get more votes *because they attract wider audience*. The more specific, difficult, technical questions you ask (or answer), the fewer are the people who even understand what you're talking about -> no votes. It definitely should be discussed in meta (I bet it has already been), but personally I'm not that interested in that number, so let's see if someone else...

Comment: @Joonas I follow a similar pattern, a subjective answer to a pointer question bagged me 6 votes (thanks to all concerened :-) ). A more tricky answer to an Android system() call - nada. :-( But I'm not here for the votes, more for the opportunity to help and learn along the way.

Comment: @Joonas, got silver or gold badges for categories?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: No. I seem to have a bronze Java badge, but no brighter ones :-)

Comment: @Joonas, that is perhaps the clearest indication if your reputation comes from technical answers or funny answers.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: It's consistent with what I wrote above: I don't know how *funny* my top-20 answers (those with tens of up-votes) are, but they're definitely *subjective* (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549600/is-there-a-fundamental-difference-between-backups-and-version-control/549621#549621). I've got at most 8 up-votes from *purely technical* answers. Looking at other peoples' answers, it's easy to see similar distribution.

Comment: Just to add a famous example: Jon Skeet's most up-voted answer is to a question called "What's your favorite “programmer ignorance” pet peeve?" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve/). His second is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284797/hello-world-in-less-than-20-bytes/284898#284898 . First subjective, second funny. Third is "What Easter Eggs have you placed in code?" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140376/what-easter-eggs-have-you-placed-in-code/140507#140507). Not exactly technical either :-)

Comment: Yeah... if you are in the U.S. and making "barely half that"... I would be scratching my head

Answer (score 21):

There are a couple of factors:

1. The type of personality that does well on social web sites (let's be ***bluntly rude*** and generalise that as the "pontificating, likes to hear self talk, theoretically-obsessed, anorak type") is by absolutely no means necessarily the type of personality who does well leading and/or working with a group of human beings (let's be ***bluntly rude*** and generalise that as the "smooching, glad-handling, compromising, deal-maker type").

As a broad rule, businesses are ***looking for the latter, not the former***.

This is both very sad (I mean sad for us pontificators) and very true.

An interesting point: ***think of your actual BOSS***, the person who has to handle all your problems all day, make you feel at least OK about yourself, balance everyone's renumeration, try to keep enough money coming in to your department so that all of you can feed your children while you fondle memory algorithms, deal with the chumps upstairs in management so you don't have to, and so on.  ***Would you really give a flying crap if that poor person has any connection, whatsoever, to some chat website?*** Of course the answer is no, you just want your boss to be good at to pulling off all that juggling.

1. Talk about "superstars" (let's be bluntly rude again) is a little star-struck. You're a superstar if you're so clever you've made millions (or at least the odd hundred thousand) because you're so clever. Oh, by the way, to do, that as well as being so clever, you have to as an incidental matter be utterly A+ rated at memory management and tricky algorithms.  If you're looking at only the latter incidental part, i.e., being utterly A+ rated at memory management and tricky algorithms, then ***sadly --- horribly ---- unfaily ---- bitterly ---- how can the world be so miserable? ----*** you're "just" someone who's utterly A+ rated at memory management and tricky algorithms.

(OK, for all this bitterness and sadness, there is the exception of the extremely small number of purely extremely technical, really research, type ways to make money - in those cases sure, the only thing that matters is your various research breakthroughs, perhaps as a humorous side issue your amazing score on grouptheoryoverflow, and so on.  But there are so few such jobs it's probably not really in the spirit of the question "getting a job in the real world." And - bitterly - they don't pay that much.)

1. The question further is emphasising "high paying" jobs.  (We'll ignore the issue of whether $100,000 p/a is high paying or not, since Bernanke's hyperinflation makes it hard to keep up with such numbers.) It's probably sadly even more true that the kind of realistic bitterness outlined in this answer, is more and more and more true if you are talking about not merely "a job" (where you are expected to ***do something*** specific that you will be told to do, provide a cog in the process), but A Real Job (where you are expected to ***positively generate massive amounts of money for the company somehow or other as a matter of course, day in and day out***)

It's hard to keep up with current salaries everywhere; it could be that "$100,000 !" fits in to the "rare purely proufoundly technical" job I mention in the aside just above.

However, the spirit of the question in some sense seems to be - to paraphrase and simplify - do top jobs have anything much to do with specifically purely technical, mathematical, expertise?

Sadly the answer there is pretty much definitively no.

It's more the "smooching, glad-handling, compromising, deal-maker type" - or, if you prefer to be bitter in another direction - the "big picture, ideas driven and generating and follow-through type" - that can - simply - ***generate*** enough money that some business can afford to give the person that much money.

Don't forget - to say you want to "earn" some fabulous salary, what you're essentially saying is ***you can generate jobs***.  How so? If you're making 200k somewhere, you're a horse that is carrying a number (10? 25?) normal "do a job" employees on your back. You have to be a producer.

It is, sadly, difficult to see how some essentially test of excellence of technical knowledge (SO chat web site) can help with that.

Steve Jobs said it all - good engineers (he said) are not merely worth 10 or 20 ordinary engineers, they are worth some 100s of ordinary engineers ... they can generate that much product, stuff, free monthly cashflow, for the company.  I think that's more what Jobs would think of as one of his superstars. It's difficult to see how ***purely*** the technical aspect (***a necessity***) can bring that.

If that's the sense of the question in terms of "big jobs," then that's probably the answer.

Comment: +1 For the vitriol and stating the truth that capability and intellect are not necessarily linked with high status or salary in the modern world.  If I could give +10, I would.

Answer (score 18):

I personally turned a sizable Stack Overflow rep and a higher (relative to the site) Hacker News reputation into a job, though I do not make $100K/year (which as a number matters more depending on the location of the job). SO and HN gave me a 'body of work' that showed off that I was passionate about my work, able to relate to others, demonstrate some level of technical competence, understand people's problems and clearly communicate solutions. And since the job is as a Developer Evangelist, these are all highly-desirable skills for that position.

I tweeted the other day that the perfect resume would be your Stack Overflow profile and your GitHub profile plus some other social interaction history like Hacker News or Twitter.

P.S. If this sounds like you, [we're hiring](http://www.twilio.com/company/jobs).

Comment: Just looked at your project. Awesome!!!

Comment: right project, wrong country (*sob*)

Comment: I disagree with your "perfect resume" idea - I think it's focused on a very small part of a very large domain. As humans we tend to associate with people who mirror ourselves - so if you've spent time building a profile on Stack Overflow, Hacker News etc you may eventually forget that there is a world of people out there who have never even heard of those. Some of those people are the best programmers you'll ever meet. I have to confess I've never heard of Hacker News. Having said that, I do take your point.

Comment: I just realized that you could troll for candidates here! DOH! If you have an SO rep > 100 and professional experience in cross platform client (C++/boost/qt or Flex) or server( JBOSS, E2C, PhP, cloud servers) applications, then [we are hiring](http://affinegy.com/about/)!  Sorry, but even a seven digit rep will still require an interview. ;)

Answer (score 14):

Having something to point at is certainly a good way to *demonstrate* a general competency in an area - that it is something you actually know about (and can articulate helpfully), rather than just some blank labels copied onto your CV - "XML, Ajax, JSON" isn't nearly as convincing as something someone can *look* at. It also opens up various potential discussion topics, etc., so having a findable (typically via google against your name) public persona is certainly never a bad thing. Unless the only thing on your public persona is garbage...

Speaking more personally, my presence on Stack Overflow **very certainly** helped me get my current job - I now work for... Stack Overflow! However, I have been approached a *number* of times by people seeing my posts; in relation to employment, consultancy, and tech-article opportunities. I was also contacted by a Google recruiter who (when introducing themselves) directly cited my Stack Overflow posts (by this time I was already working for Stack Overflow, so I thanked them for their consideration, but I didn't choose to interview).

Of course, getting a public persona out there can *also* be done in a range of other ways; blogging, hobby-projects, public-speaking (user-groups), etc. So how about another reason to use Stack Overflow:

### I learn something every single day...

...either by spending a minute-or-two researching an answer, or just by reading the other replies to an interesting post. The questions can be equally interesting, especially when introducing unexpected behaviour*. And learning is *never* a bad thing.

### Still not enough?

Then consider this. We have *unicorns*! That should be enough for anyone.

*=for example, just this morning I found out that Visual Studio with the debugging host-process enabled processes attributes on the entry-point (AKA `Main()`) differently to the core [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) execution.

Comment: Marc, I don't think you've emphasized the unicorns enough: [Stack Overflow NYC world headquarters!!](http://yfrog.com/f580890494j) :)

Comment: @Ahmad - to be honest, I don't think the unicorn saw what was coming. It got ugly. It put up a defence, though - the beating-stick broke before we hit unicorn blood (true story).

Comment: Totally unrelated - does anyone else think Marc looks like New Zealand cricket captain Daniel Vettori http://www.google.com/images?q=daniel+vettori&biw=1024&bih=582 - at least from your profile image

Comment: @Jose - ask yourself this: *have you ever seen us in the same room?*; eh? eh? If not... how do you know I don't dabble in both?

Comment: Well, cos your blog/SO profile shows you've been coding at the same time I'm watching Dan on TV ;)

Answer (score 13):

I hate to break it to you but...

**High SO rep != great programmer**

Actually, many of them are. However, there are some users that are on the site so much, answering so many questions **but their average score per answer is very low** yet that still have a 5 digit rep due to their high activity.

If there's enough data there, an interviewer could possibly read answers to gleen insights into their approaches to solving problems but to go on straight score would make a company look downright silly.

Comment: In addition, users earn reputation by *asking* questions as well.

Comment: what's wrong with asking questions? a good question is at least as insightful as a good answer!

Comment: good answers in niche areas tend to have low scores.

Comment: I tend to agree.  If I were hiring someone into a developer support position at a big place like Microsoft or Apple I would certainly greatly value a high SO rep.  Clearly the high SO posters will be excellent teachers and developer supporters.

On the other hand, it's certainly the case that many great programmers don't have any SO rep at all. 

If hiring an actual developer an high SO rep is a 'nice to have', I see little evidence that SO rep strongly correlates to actual development talent.

Answer (score 12):

Consider what it takes to get a good Stack Overflow rating...

- intelligence
- knowledge
- experience
- good language skills
- immense amounts of "free" time

Now take the last point there, people who have very high reputations here take a great deal of time to answer the questions of the masses.  Now whilst hugely thankful for such benevolent people, this implies one of the following.

1. They are unemployed
2. They are self-employed and have a
   lot of "free" time
3. They are employed and spend all
   their personal time sitting at a
   screen *(for example, "in want of a life")*
4. They are employed and waste working
   hours answering non-business
   questions.

All but number three are reasons for a prospective employer not to take you on, and the third makes you wonder if they are ideal for spending all day with.

Anyhow, my boss is watching my screen a bit so I had better stop this post, before I have to use my Stack Overflow reputation to get me a new job...

Comment: I don't think this is entirely true. For instance, i have a long commute and sometimes I answer questions on the bus. I also sometimes answer a few questions on the weekend before going out. I answer a few questions at lunch during work and I do admit sometimes even during work hours. However SO has also helped me learn things I needed for work, so it works itself out. I think you are just generalizing here.

Comment: @Stan Well given my last sentence on my post, I assumed that the tongue-in-cheek nature of it would stand out.  I myself regularly use SO during work hours as a repository of useful answers to questions.  Giving something back is only fair, not that my boss would agree.  As for your example uses, I think they would come under 3 and 4 and yes, generalising.

Comment: @Stan I think that could easily qualifies as "personal time". You could be talking to someone, or reading a book (technical or even a novel) ;-)

Comment: i chuckled at your last sentence, but I didn't know if the whole post was tongue-in-cheek. I guess work has really dulled my sense of humor.. :D

Comment: Well there was humour there, but also the serious point that a hefty rating could be viewed negatively by a prospective employer as time wasting. Also some employers, bad ones as a rule, frown on giving help to other companies, anything the coders do is "mine all mine", etc. My boss's favourite question regarding my work is "Is it all proprietary? I own it all right?" :-| I imagine he will be visited by 3 ghosts this Christmas Eve.

Answer (score 11):

My current job pays me about $54k a year for 25h a week, most of which I work from home. Plus working as a game developer was kind of a childhood dream, that has now come true (although I sometimes think of moving on to something more "meaningful"). So I suppose my job is arguably equivalent to or even better than the average $100k+ jobs you get as a developer.

On my application I added a section "participation in online communities", wherein I listed SO (and a few smaller german forums). I don't have a superbly high score, but among ActionScript 3 developers I am very well placed.

The references I had were not really outstanding. Mostly the stupid kind of stuff you do as a Flash Developer to get money for sites you'd never visit yourself. But upon arrival to the interview I immediatly sensed, that I had a very high standing from the start. I have personally accounted this to my SO activity.

Getting a high rep on SO means, that you are eager to exchange thoughts, that you are knowledgeable enough to solve the problems your peers pose you (real problems from they actually encounter in every day life), and that you are able to communicate your ideas. These are key abilities for good developers. Thus one can say, people who have a high rep on SO have those abilities. The reputation is given to you by independent developers, not by some comittees or someone vaguely in touch with the subject. I think a high rep on SO is a much better measure than good grades (which appearently are still consider a criterium by some employers).

That being said, I'd never hire someone just because they have a high SO rep. But let's say a person with a high rep will have a head start while trying to convince me they're good. Appearently my current employer reasons similarly.

Answer (score 11):

### Yes…*ish*

I’ve got (for want of a better term) job “invitations” via email which explicitly mention my Stack Overflow profile, from companies that boast a 12/12 score on the [Joel Test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) and which honestly seem like extremely cool work environments.

And I know that the same has happened to several other people.

### But …

I don’t believe for a second that I (or any of the other people) would score a job **without an interview**. Like most others here, I think that Stack Overflow may help you to get exposure on the web. But that’s all. It merely gets your name out. It shows that you’re active and motivated but not whether you’re *qualified*.

Comment: Don't you think it's because your unicorn is red?

Comment: @Konrad almost anybody can get high rep if they put enough effort in it. I'd guess you got those job offers because your answers are very good (although the rep probably helped). But I doubt that someone who has 50k rep would automatically get job offers if he'd only given many mediocre answers (those do get rep after all).

Comment: "Job offers" aren't the same thing as Job Offers (i.e. Sign on the line and come in on Monday). Lets be clear about the difference here...

Comment: @Paul: I’m not sure what you mean. But I *did* make it clear that your SO reputation will not guarantee you a job, contrary to what Joel said.

Comment: @Konrad: (At least in the US) when I say that a company made me a job offer, I mean that they officially offered me a precise salary and position in the company. Usually this means that I've already interviewed, signed the NDA, passed the background and references check, etc. What I typically get via email are job inquiries - they want to know if I'm interested in going further with their company. They may be very serious about that, but they're not job offers until the choice about whether or not I work for the company is entirely up to me.

Comment: @Paul: thanks for the info. Didn’t know that. I’ll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for a good paying job, my recommendations are as follows:

1. Love what you do and be passionate about it.
2. Educate yourself, don't fools others - Most people neglect the fundamentals and jump into the advance stuff thinking it'll make them look smart. All tall buildings are built upon a stable foundation.
3. Know your worth - Don't accept a job only because the employeer said they want to hire you. It's a two way street. What are they offering you long term? Is there growth? Does the work appeal to you?
4. Good pay is subjective, so know what you're willing to accept and settle for nothing less.
5. Build a reputation! Speak at conferences, Write articles, commit to Open Source projects

Don't be lazy. Just because someone will Google your name up and find out you answered a million questions on stackexchange.com that it makes you any way qualified for more money. Any code monkey can use Google to answer a question. Problem solving, strong technical knowledge, good personal skills, etc. make the world of difference when it comes to money.

I'm not perfect. Just perfect enough to know I'm good, but I'm not sure how good.

Comment: +1 Pretty good I'd say.  A wise man knows that he knows nothing, etc.  Entirely valid and important points.

Answer (score 7):

If you spend time getting 5-digit reputation on Stack Overflow then you probably know what you're doing. That, more than any numerical value, is what get you the jobs.

Answer (score 6):

Beyond landing a job, Stack Overflow can be of great benefit for independent developers and consultants.  By demonstrating knowledge in a specific area, along with the ability to communicate what you know, you can become very attractive to someone looking for a consultant in that area.

I've been contacted on several occasions by individuals and companies who were looking to hire me as a contractor, based solely on an answer or two that I had left on Stack Overflow.  I don't have the time to consult, so I can't say what those opportunities would have been worth.  A couple of them sounded interesting, though.

However, I've received a greater number of these requests from the non-Stack-Overflow content that I've put out there like my course, the open source projects I've worked on, and the guides that I've published on my blog.  All of this public information can help to identify you as an expert in an area.  Think of how many people use the phrase "he wrote the book on that" when speaking about an authority on a subject.

Overall, I look at Stack Overflow as a way of keeping my skills sharp, while at the same time giving back for all of the help I've received from others over the years.  I take time that I would have wasted on blogs, etc. and channel it here.  If it benefits my career, that's a great side effect.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe Joel's implicitly offering a job to anyone with a 5-digit reputation? On a more serious note, some employers do follow sites like this, and also open source projects and mailing lists. I was contacted by a firm about a job opportunity a few years ago based on a recommendation from someone I worked on an open source project with. Having a reputation for being knowledgeable and helpful surely has to count for something.

Answer (score 4):

It may be of benefit as a decider I'd say. Like [MS certifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719239)

It'd never be the sole reason to employ someone.

It might be a reason to not employ someone if they spend many hours a day here...

Comment: @Pierre 303: I can get a job on my good looks alone :-)

Comment: Sure you'll get ANY job by putting this picture on you CV :)

Comment: Except for the cases where MS certs hurt you. I know several technical people hiring in non-MS shops who specifically tell HR not to forward anything with many of those. It tends to be a sign that you didn't have enough fires to put out at your real job.

Comment: @Paul McMillan: I wouldn't expect MS Certs to help in a non MS shop :-)

Comment: @gbn: but many people don't realize that they can actively detract.

Comment: @gbn I do the interviewing for a non-MS shop and MS certifications are certainly a decider! Just like Paul said. ;-)

Comment: @Paul McMillan, @Orbling: Any muppet who sports MS certs for a non-MS job deserves what they get. Ditto some Oracle certified bod pitching for a SQL Server role... MS Certs was an example of course in case you're wondering

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Maybe less so now, but more so in the future. I'm gainfully employed, but I have had 4 google interviews, and all the front line HR people asked me questions that they could only have learned if they googled me and my contributions in other sites (perhaps the thing that hurts stackexchange is the alias - rather than a direct name response). It's only a matter of time before they make the leap to asking for aliases on sites like stack exchange.

Comment: Were the HR guys trying to know if you are active in forums, such as these?

Answer (score 4):

I've gotten job offers before solely based on participation in online forums. The way I see it, it doesn't automatically get you hired, but it can be a way to get noticed.

However, I've been at my first and only job for exactly 6 years today, and am not planning to jump ship. Therefore, I don't participate in online forums to pad my resume. I do it to help people and to check whether I really am as clever as I think I am ;)

I don't think participation in stackoverflow is a particularly efficient way to get an "in" with prospective employers. I can think of lots of better ways to make myself more "marketable", if I wanted to do that. If marketability is your motivation to be here, you might as well not bother.

Answer (score 4):

### I Sure Wish

Yeah... I really do. Having almost a five figure SO-rating, in my geographical area, nobody really cares and finding a new job is quite a daunting task still.

It all boils down to your contact network and experience.

Answer (score 4):

The head of computer science at my university insisted that my high grades would open doors.  That only seemed to be the case at the university itself.  In fact, some employers I interviewed with considered my grades to be somewhat low, because my school had lower 'grade targets' than the university local to that company.

Stack Overflow reputation demonstrably helps your chances in getting a career with Stack Overflow.  Beyond that, it really depends on the company.

Answer (score 3):

A nice opportunity, your skills and (hopefully) a good recruiter will get you the job. Reputation in SO (or others) is as likely to help you as to fire back at you. There's many ego wars going on in here...

Answer (score 3):

When I start my own company in the next 1-2 years, high reputation score in stackoverflow will be the 1st criteria for me to hire developers. I hope when that time comes, stackoverflow still serving the humanity.

Answer (score 3):

Common sense, team play and people skills are as much important as technical skills. It's better to have a decent score overall.

Dealing with 'Hi Tech' bosses with low score in other skills is a nightmare.

Comment: Does a high SO score not imply a certain level of common sense, team play, and people skills though?

Comment: Maybe a bit of good of common sense :)

Comment: +1 For actually mentioning soft skills.  The rarest skill set available in programmers it seems to me, and the most desired by employers often!

Comment: +1 for "Dealing with 'Hi Tech' bosses with low score in other skills is a nightmare."

Comment: If you put common sense on your CV, I'd throw it in the trash.

Answer (score 3):

A high SO score can get your foot in the door at plenty of jobs.  But it's always the interview that makes or breaks you.  If you're bad at interviewing (like me), then a high SO score will get you the interview but not the job.

Answer (score 2):

If I was to hire, I would rather see how the person performs in the interview.

Comment: I would rather see how the person performs in the job :)

Comment: @Pierre 303 That's why you should make candidates do the job during the interview.

Comment: @Pierre : How would you know that before an interview ? References ?

Comment: @Geek: I was just enforcing what you said

Comment: @Geek: You don't know that before an interview and as a rule you do not know it after the interview.  I always set an exam, and never take people on without a trial in the job first.  We give them two weeks, post interview/exam if good, see what they are made of, then up that to 3 months if they are good.  If we still want them after that, then we give them a job offer.

Comment: @Orb: Three months of stress, this wont be possible in my country unless the compensation part is too good. You must be having people who drop out on thier own after three months ?? Do you hire them on contract for three months ?

Comment: @Geek Aye, zero-hour contract, they work, if they want to leave fine, no notice, if we want them to, same.  Money is not brilliant usually, fairly standard practice in the UK to have probation periods like that.  Some companies do it for a year, though there are legal obligations to employees after three months, so that's why we put the mark there.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not. Look at it from a different perspective:

1. How many 5-digit SO users are looking/willing to accept another job for "only" 100K?
2. What percentage of people looking to fill 100K jobs have ever heard of SO and if so would use it as a criteria for hiring?

Some day they may be able to make the connection between SO scores and their job & CV posting site.

Maybe another question would be, would you consider SO scores for hiring?

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of [Drake's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation) in astronomy. It is an equation that is suppose to give a statistical hint of the number of civilizations in the universe. It is a waste of time actually because it assumes that involved parameters are independent while they are clearly not.

I have four children and a good job. Maybe that is the key to the good job?

Comment: Yes, some posters already mentioned that there is no direct correlation, although the observation maybe true.

Comment: @Gunner: Yes you are right. I the correlation in the question might be positive though - which is probably not the case in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking as someone who spends **way** to much time at SO:

If I'm looking to hire someone, their reputation on SO is not going to be a consideration.  At all.  Their rep on SO is going to tell me nothing about their work habits or their suitability to the job.  For that, I'm going to look at their documented work experience and any products they have for review (web sites, open source projects, etc.) as well as their performance in an interview or series of interviews.

SO is a great resource, but not for screening potential hires.

Comment: Aren't questions and answers on SO some kind of documented work experience or knowledge of potential candidates?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can have intimate knowledge of a particular language or technology and still be a crap developer, or a pain in the ass to work with.  SO isn't a professional organization on the order of the IEEE or ACM.

Answer (score 1):

A good SO flow is just one of the signals that will get you noticed (amongst others such as a high gpa, open-source contributions, certifications, etc). Most probably it will just get you the interview. After that, its all upto your performance during the 5-6 hour onsite interview and coding solutions on the whiteboard to complex algorithm problems (atleast at the top tech companies). While SO does discuss algorithms and data structures, there is no guarantee that every SO user with a 5 digit score knows or would do well in a high-pressure whiteboard coding interview.

Comment: Also being a technical genius doesn't guarantee you are a great developer. I've seen many of them being thrown out of the company because they were unable to work in teams.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO: Depends on what Q&A's you contributed on SO to earn a 5-digit rep. If the Q&A's that earned you a 5-digit rep are related to a jobs requirements which is in high demand, then most likely it will help you get the $100K+ job, but its just one of many factors (technical know-how and problem-solving) but what about the rest of the ingridients that go into being hired?

Answer (score 1):

High reputation on SO might get you into the hiring process, might even give you small bonus, but that's it. In my experience, actually gives you less, than let's say participation in groups on LinkedIn (note, that there is no reputation system there).

The problem with SO rep is, that it does not necessarily reflect much. There are few types of very high scoring answers, that have nothing to do with actual skills:

- obvious answer to obvious question posted few seconds faster, then 10 other identical answers;
- popular answer to argumentative question, which should be community wiki, but was posted by a newbie;
- c'n'p answers to duplicate questions;
- sarcastic answers to really stupid questions;

Thus just the number without actually looking at the answers is meaningless.

Answer (score -5):

John skeet got a job in Google as well, he has a good score on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Person A got a good job, Person A has a high reputation. Correlation does not imply causation.

Comment: I think the person was asking examples so this can be an example :-)

Comment: This isn't an example, this is correlation. I got an amazing job at Facebook making $200k / yr and I happen to smoke 4 packs a day. Did I get the job due to my smoking habits? **Probably not**.

Comment: Well that way everything will be a correlation. You got a job at facebook and you are a guy. Did you get the job because you were a guy ? What is an example BTW ?

Comment: I believe that he was hired by Google before StackOverflow opened.

Comment: @James: Causation would be *"I got an email from Google who mentioned they found me browsing high reputation users on StackOverflow."*

Comment: @Josh, even better would be a framed thank-you notice from Larry and Sergey to Joel and Jeff for creating StackOverflow .

Comment: @Thorb: That *would* be better.

Comment: @Thor: that, by the way, is long overdue. ;-)

Comment: @Josh K: What brand do you smoke?

Comment: @AD: It was an example. ;) **Disclaimer:** I don't work at Facebook and I don't smoke... often.